# SpringBoot Controller Not Being Mapped

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to create a basic SpringBoot web-app with one endpoint called /movies. I followed some of the docs on the site and also a basic Youtube tutorial on it.

The app returns **'it works'** when I run **curl localhost:8080** from the command line but when I attempt to access my endpoint /movies I see that 'The requested URL **/movies** was not found on this server.'

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movie_service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Movie> getAllMovies(){
        return movie_service.getAllMovies();
    }
}
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>MovieDCU</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried almost every suggested answer on this site for similar questions posted but nothing seems to fix it. One unusual thing is that I don't see the mappings when I run the app, in the command line:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2019-11-23 13:27:19.243  INFO 30238 --- [           main] com.Main                                 : Starting Main on Conors-MB with PID 30238 (/Users/eclipse-workspace/Movie/target/classes started by x in /Users/eclipse-workspace/Movie)
2019-11-23 13:27:19.249  INFO 30238 --- [           main] com.Main                                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-23 13:27:20.011  INFO 30238 --- [           main] com.Main                                 : Started Main in 1.209 seconds (JVM running for 1.611)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the package of those two classes? How comes it returns "it works"? Where's the code doing that?

Comment: Your controller looks fine to me.  Is that the only logging output you're seeing when you start the app?  By default there should be more.

Comment: Your app hasn’t started Tomcat so another process must be listening on port 8080 and serving “It works”. I would guess that one of Tomcat’s jars was corrupted by Maven when it downloaded it. Try clearing Maven’s cache and rebuilding your application.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for that. I had nothing running in terms of applications but something was still using that port. I ran it on 8090 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your class like this.
Just have the GetMapping at the method level. Also notice I have renamed your service to the standard Java naming convention (camelCase).

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping("/movies")
    public Collection<Movie> getAllMovies(){
        return movieService.getAllMovies();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Linux machine, then you could have default apache server started.